# IE8 issue - jQuery adjusting navigation html when page resizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Using the below code, I don't want IE8 to pick up the responsive navigation. When a window is resized, IE8 is removing navigation. My  has a class of "lt-ie9" for IE8. Can you tell me how to adjust the code so if the browser size is below 767, it will use the desktop version.

```
function resizeNav() {
if (!nav) {
        nav = {};
        nav.root = jQuery('#navigation');
        nav.primary = nav.root.find('.menu');
        nav.secondary = jQuery('.secondary-links');
        nav.moveable = nav.secondary.children('li');
        nav.icon = jQuery('<div id="menu-icon" class="btn">Navigation</div>');

        nav.icon.click(function () {
            nav.primary.slideToggle('slow');
            nav.icon.toggleClass('active');
        });
    }

    // Position everything
    if (getWidth() <= 767) {
        nav.moveable.appendTo(nav.primary);
        nav.root.prepend(nav.icon);
        nav.primary.hide();
    } else {
        nav.moveable.appendTo(nav.secondary);
        nav.icon.detach();
        nav.primary.show();
    }

    nav.icon.removeClass('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `lt-ie9` class is added the `html` element, the easiest way to do this is just check for it along with the width:

```
if (!html.lt-ie9 && getWidth() <= 767) {
```

You could also store the `lt-ie9` as a boolean to be more efficient:

```
var isLtIe9 = $('html.lt-ie9').length;
```

And then modify the above to:

```
if (!isLtIe9 && getWidth() <= 767) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use JS if you only want to effect IE8? Wouldn't it be better to just use an IE8 only CSS file. This would keep your code clean and hack free.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```